# Relation between the Axiom of Choice and a the existence of a hyperplane not containing a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

In a lot of problems in linear algebra one uses the existence, for each $E$ vector space over a field $k$, and each $x\in E$, of a Hyperplane $H$ such that $E=k\cdot x \oplus H$ (Let us denote $\mathcal{P}$ this property). With Zorn's Lemma, the existence of a such $H$ is trivial. However, as this seems weaker than the existence of a basis of $E$, maybe $\mathcal{P}$ does not imply the Axiom of choice. Thus my question is: is $\mathcal{P}$ equivalent to the Axiom of Choice and if not, is there a weaker form of the Axiom of Choice equivalent to $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: Just for the record, choice is definitely necessary to show this result: taking $E$ to be $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb Q$-vector space, $H$ would have to be a subset of $\mathbb R$ isomorphic to $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$, but it is consistent that this set can't be linearly ordered.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not hard to see that this statement is equivalent to "In every vector space, for every vector $v$ there is a functional $f$ such that $f(v)=1$".

If $\cal P$ holds, then the projection onto $k\cdot x$ is a linear functional which is nontrivial; if there is a nontrivial functional then choose $x$ which is mapped to $1_k$, and consider $H$ as the kernel of the functional. Some $\cal P$ is equivalent to "If $V$ is nontrivial, then $V^*$ is nontrivial".

As of October 2018, it is still unknown whether or not this is equivalent to the axiom of choice in full. But there are some intermediate results, for example it is consistent that there is a vector space over a field $k$ whose dual is trivial, for any fixed $k$. Moreover, this is consistent with $\sf DC_\kappa$ for any prescribed $\kappa$.

One should remark that restricting to Banach spaces and continuous functionals, the nontriviality of the [topological] dual is equivalent to the Hahn–Banach theorem.

Let me also add that Marianne Morillon showed that in $\sf ZFA$, $\cal P(\Bbb Q)$, namely restricting our attention to vector spaces over $\Bbb Q$, is not enough to deduce that every vector space over $\Bbb Q$ admits a basis, and that a weaker form of choice called "Axiom of Multiple Choice" implies $\cal P$ for fields of characteristics $0$.

> *Morillon, Marianne*, [**Linear forms and axioms of choice.**](http://www.emis.de/journals/CMUC/cmuc0903/cmuc0903.htm), Commentat. Math. Univ. Carol. 50, No. 3, 421-431 (2009). [ZBL1212.03034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1212.03034).

These two facts are not telling us a whole lot about what happens in $\sf ZF$, since in $\sf ZF$ the axiom of multiple choice implies full choice.

Comment: Would not the dual of a line bundle without nonzero sections provide an example of a nonzero (in fact, 1-dimensional) vector space without nonzero functionals on it? More precisely, the space of such functionals would be 1-dimensional itself but would fail to have any (global) elements.

Comment: I have literally no idea what any of that means.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე 1-dimensional vector space always has nonzero functionals - if $v$ is nonzero vector, then every vector is of the form $\alpha v$ and $\alpha v\mapsto\alpha$ is a nonzero functional. I think your confusion might arise from misunderstanding what "nonzero" here is supposed to mean - it just means any functional which is not zero everywhere. This is different from vector bundle terminology, where "nonzero" means that it's everywhere nonzero.

Comment: @Wojowu (1) It might happen that the statement "every vector is of the form $\alpha v$" does not imply that you can consistently pick these $\alpha$s for all vectors at once, no?  (2) Does not "nonzero" mean "everywhere nonzero" in the present context too? A linear functional on a 1-dimensional vector space is either identically zero or bijective.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: (1) Of course it does. It's a vector space, $\alpha$ is unique once you've fixed $v$. (2) No, $0$ is always sent to $0$. So you cannot be zero everywhere.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე (1) this $\alpha$ is necessarily unique. (2) No, "nonzero functional" is simply "any functional except the zero functional". Also, note that any functional will be zero at the zero vector, so there is no "everywhere nonzero functional".

Comment: (2) I should say "nonzero except at zero", sorry. In other words, the kernel of a linear functional on a 1-dimensional space is either zero or the whole space. And given that, I must admit I am confused about (1): I completely agree that unique existence implies global existence; on the other hand, there certainly exist line bundles with global sections but without global functionals on them: e. g. $\mathcal O(1)$ on the projective line is one such.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I have no idea what is a line bundle. But a $1$-dimensional vector space, fix $v$, then if $w=\alpha\cdot v$ and $w=\beta\cdot v$, then $0=w-w=\alpha\cdot v-\beta\cdot v=(\alpha-\beta)\cdot v$, and therefore $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: In fact I now realized that my attempts are useless anyway: axiom of choice obviously fails in sheaves over $\mathcal O(1)$; and I also have no idea whether every line bundle admitting nonzero global form implies that AC holds in sheaves on the space in question.

Comment: Hey no wait, for a, say, connected space with trivial Picard group every line bundle will be trivial but AC will nevertheless fail!

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Let me point out yet again, I have literally no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry. In fact most probably all I said is still useless. For what I say to work you probably need to violate excluded middle. In other words, I am speaking about essentially non-Boolean Heyting-valued models. I don't have any Boolean-valued examples, let alone their ultrafilter quotients or whatever...

Comment: On the afterthought - something Boolean-valued might stem from a permutation model, if there were a group that does not admit any nontrivial representations over some field. I have no idea whether such thing exists.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Again, I am not sure what you mean. But feel free to send me an email with details. My address can be found through my profile.

Comment: The statement in the question was "for *each* $x$ ... there is $H$ ...." So I think the equivalent statement should not be just that there is a non-zero linear functional but that, for each vector $x\neq 0$, there is a linear functional $f$ with $f(x)\neq0$.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks, I've changed that and added some references to match.

Comment: Another equivalent formulation is "a system of linear equations over a field F has a solution in F if and only if every finite sub-system has a solution in F."  The big advantage of this reformulation is that it's in the Howard-Rubin book "Consequences of the Axiom of Choice" as form 284, so one can look up what's known about it. Unfortunately, it turns out that essentially nothing is known.